# Ubuntu Docker image broken out of the box?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, boot2docker

Should the following work out of the box?

```
$ docker pull ubuntu:14.04
$ docker run -ti ubuntu:14.04
root@8f0dcfdae9b6:/# apt-get update
```

Sadly, I get:

```
...
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [146 kB]
Fetched 2490 kB in 8s (284 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So I started going down the rabbit whole of adding GPG keys manually, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566195/signatures-not-verified), but it seems nuts that the official Ubuntu image would be so broken out of the box.

Is this a Docker thing, or do you think something's broken in Ubuntu's archives?

[EDIT]

Tried Ubuntu 14.04.2 as well.

[EDIT 2]

Happens only on Boot2docker / OS X. On Ubuntu (host system) this does not recreate. I've tried upgrading boot2docker (to 1.8) and starting with a fresh ISO image, but that doesn't help.

Comment: Close vote? Is docker considered to be non development? I don't think sysadmins would necessarily know more about docker than developers. I think dev-ops questions are relevant for SO.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is an issue with the older Ubuntu in general and not limited to Docker.

Try `ubuntu:14.04.2`

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the only thing that worked, after trying to set GPG keys manually with `apt-key adv` to no avail, what so overwrite the apt `sources.list` file with entries generated by [this tool](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php).

To be clear, I still receive warnings about some packages failing to be verified, but at least after the update the actual installation of the packages I'm dependent on succeed. So this isn't really a solution, more like a hack.